# PHP MySQL InnoDB Unix Windows case sensitive table names

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, case-sensitive

The problem is that deployment MySQL DB is on Linus, and development MySQL DB on Windows.
DB is InnoDB. So arose the problem with case-sensitive names of tables.
I found solution like:

```
function getTableName($table_name){
    $query="select TABLE_NAME from `information_schema`.`TABLES` where table_name
     like '%$table_name%' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query,$this->connection);
    $err_number=mysql_errno($this->connection);

    if (!$err_number){
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($num_rows==1){
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $row["TABLE_NAME"];
        }else {
            return "";
        }

    }else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

So name it have be indipendant from type of OS. But may be exist options of MySQL to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) option

Comment: I like this answer (+1 for this one) not only because it's concise and to-the-point, but it is vital for InnoDB. Constraint names are case sentivite and do not migrate very well. Changing table names to lower case do not make the constraints budge. Even after applying this option, check all constraints to make sure the are all lower case as well. This is particularly important when migrating InnoDB from Linux to Windows.